# DataGrid column can not be sorted if contains Date or Byte

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` with autogenerated columns. Columns with `String` values can be sorted by clicking on header, but columns with `Byte` and `Date` values not.

Why and how to allow sorting them?

Comment: Please provide some code. I've just made a simple test and it is not like what you said. I can click on `Byte` column header and it is sorted normally.